Is there a way to change type while maintaining the optional state of the type?
I would like to change the data of some fields to a customized type.
For example, I would like to change the b field of TSomeType to a custom type to get TSomeTypeConverted type as a result.
// original type
type TSomeType = {
    a: boolean;
    b: string;
}
// result what I want
type TSomeTypeConverted = {
    a: boolean;
    b: TCustomType;
}

Similar results were obtained by applying the TConvertToCustomType below.
type TConvertToCustomType<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {[P in K]: TCustomType};

type TSomeTypeConverted = TConvertToCustomType<TSomeType, 'b'>
/* type TSomeTypeConverted = {
    a: boolean;
    b: TCustomType;
} */

However, in the process, all optional values are changed to required.
// before
type TSomeType = {
    a: boolean;
    b: string;
    c?: string; // optional
}
type TSomeTypeConverted = TConvertToCustomType<TSomeType, 'b' | 'c'>
/* type TSomeTypeConverted = {
    a: boolean;
    b: TCustomType;
    c: TCustomType; // not optional anymore
} */

Is there a way to change only the type while maintaining the optional status?

You can use Mapped Types with Conditional Type, instead of Omit & object:
type TConvertToCustomType<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? TCustomType : T[P] };

type TSomeTypeConverted = TConvertToCustomType<TSomeType, 'b' | 'c'>
/* type TSomeTypeConverted = {
    a: boolean;
    b: TCustomType;
    c?: TCustomType; // preserves optional flag
} */

Playground Link

It works perfectly. Thank you!
I was using the type below, but your type is much shorter and easier to understand
export type TConvertToCustomType <T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {   [P in K]: undefined extends T[P] ? TCustomType | undefined : TCustomType; };
